# Active Learning (e.g. Pool Sampling) for SVM in python

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm

I'm working on a problem that would greatly benefit from an active learning protocol (e.g. given a set of unlabeled data as compared to an existing model, the algorithm requests that a subset of unlabeled data be labeled by an 'oracle').

Does anyone have any examples of active learning (either using pool sampling, query by committee, or otherwise) being implemented in a SVM (preferably in python)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Implementing active learning in python is quite straight forward. For simpliest case you just select new sample to query, which has smallest absolute value of decision_function on your learned SVM (simple uncertainty sampling), which is basically a single line long!. Assuming that you have a binary classification, with trained svm in `clf` and some unlabeled examples in `X`, you simply select

```
sample = X[np.argmin(np.abs(clf.decision_function(X)))]
```

You can find many different implementations on github too, like the one for AL paper from last year's ECML: https://github.com/gmum/mlls2015

Comment: This looks fantastic! After poking around a bit, I can't seem to see why this single line of code wouldn't also work on a 3+ classification problem as well, though? Also, it looks like swapping np.argmin (modeling refinement) could be swapped out for np.argmax (increasing domain of applicability of your dataset).

Comment: for more classes decision_function returns a matrix, and argmin will flatten it and return index in flat vector, while you need a row number. Thus you will have to do two-step operation, first taking max over second axis (to take the most probable class) and then argmin to select the least certain. Swaping argmin to argmax does not make much sense for active learning, as you will query samples which you already perfectly classify, this is the exact opposite of your task (unless you expect your model to be overconfident and you query sometimes argmax to find false positives).

Answer (score 1):

Two popular query strategies for pool based sampling are uncertainty sampling and query by committee (see [paper](http://burrsettles.com/pub/settles.activelearning.pdf) for an extensive review). The following library implements three common uncertainty strategies: least confident, max margin and entropy as well as two committee strategies: vote entropy and average KL divergence: https://github.com/davefernig/alp

The library is compatible with scikit-learn and can be used with any classifier. It uses random subsampling as a baseline for measuring the benefit of active learning.